# How to set up htaccess to redirect all URLS to new domain?

Tags: htaccess

So I have domain `http://example.com`.

I want to setup htaccess to redirect all of these variations

- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `https://example.com/111`
- `http://example.com/222`

...
basically EVERYTHING on this domain I want redirect to

```
http://www.newexample.com
```

How to set it up properly in `.htaccess` file?

All domains on same server.

Path needs not to be kept.

Comment: How are the old and new sites set up?   Are they on separate servers?  Separate virtual hosts?   Both mapped to the same document root directory?    The mechanics of the redirect are going to differ depending on whether or not the sites share a document root.

Comment: All sites on new server. I just need visitors of old site to be redirected to new site. Any url they enter on old site needs to redirect them to main url of new site.

Comment: Do the sites share a document root on the new server?

Comment: When you say you want it to redirect to the new site, are you hoping to preserve the path portion of the URL.  For example `https://example.com/111` to `https://newexample.com/111`?

Comment: No, I specifically don't want to reserve path. I want everything to redirect to main domain

Comment: I provided that info. Same server for both domains. Same filesystem. Url path needs not to preserved. I need everything to redirect to new domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide from Apache should help: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

But for something you can copy and paste, [see this cheatsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/) but drop the `$1` from the Rewrite Rule.

It's easier for me to post the code than to explain:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrit­eCond %{HTTP­_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
Rewrit­eRule ^(.*)$ http:/­/ww­w.newexample.com/ [R=301,L]
```

If that doesn't work, then your hosting company is restricting the settings that you can set in `.htaccess` and you'll need to call support to get it straightened out.

Comment: Although this won't redirect EVERYTHING as stated in the question. It won't redirect `example.com` (non-www) for instance.

Comment: Right, because the `RewriteCond` looks for the (old) domain prefixed by the `www` subdomain it wouldn't impact other subdomains or the naked domain...typically, the configuration rules dictating whether or not to use `www` are in a section of their own so I didn't delve into that. I try to avoid using `.htaccess` files for performance reasons but when I do, I use the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) as a starting point, it includes configuration blocks for using `www` or not so a user can just comment out whichever is inapplicable.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your domain is on same server, on each request your server needs to work twice, one for handling with htaccess, another for serving site from correct address/domain.

What if you could do this directly from domain provider.

### Redirecting to new domain using DNS settings

Most of domian provider let's you redirect domain preserving url and with header 301 or whatever you wish to.

I recommend you check with your domain provider, go to olddomain.com's setting, instead setting up A record of the domian, choose redirect option. Enter newdomain.com and forward all query strong and path as well.

This will save tons of request from being hit on your server, and your DNS might cache new path automatically.

Check if you can implement this solution, would be really good.